# How to create a Linux Mirror for software and Manual?

Tags: linux, repository

I have a couple of servers that that are wasting resources and i would like to create linux mirrors out of them and put them at the service of the general public.

Is a mirror just as simple as exposing a public ftp folder or a simple webs erver with the large files so people can download OR are there any rules that i need to abide by? Such as GPG Keys and so forth.

Also i would like to host a couple of Linux manuals, any ideas will be appreciated?

Comment: As was pointed out in the answers, the "correct" way to mirror software varies pretty widely.  At its core a mirror is just a copy of everything in the original repository, but to *get* that copy (efficiently) you'll often need to follow specific procedures.  What those procedures are is a question to ask the project whose files you want to mirror...

Answer (score 1):

The accepted method for mirroring differs from distribution to distribution. You can even apply to mirror the main kernel repository. Here are a few examples:

- Kernel mirroring: http://www.kernel.org/mirrors/become.html
- Debian mirroring: http://www.debian.org/CD/mirroring/
- Ubuntu mirroring: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors#Country_mirror_requirements

The main thing you need is a permanent, reliable connection with unlimited bandwidth utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's just a case of regularly synchronising with an upstream mirror, and publishing the files with HTTP and possibly FTP. Some care needs to be taken when synchronising however to ensure that your mirror is always consistent from the client's perspective. This process varies according to the metadata in the archive (Debian archive, RPM repodata) but usually involves a [two stage `rsync` process](http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror#how). You then probably want to register as an official mirror with the projects which you are mirroring so that people can actually discover your mirror.